# Malformed XML in JSF 2.1 redirect

Tags: xml, jsf, jboss

I have a login page that's getting this error in only one client machine. The same application deployed in the same JBoss EAP version is working in every other server we try.

After you input your credentials, the application redirects to a home page. We are getting this weird error i haven't been able to find in any forum.

**Internet explorer:** Error [status: emptyResponse code: 200]: An empty response was received from the server. Check server error log.
XML5635: XML declarations are only permitted at the beginning of the file.

**Chrome:**  Error [status: emptyResponse code: 200]: An empty response was received from the server. Check server error log.

**Firefox:** [window] Error [status: malformedXML code:200] XML Parsing Error: junk after document element.

The server log has nothing on this error but I managed to get the response  from that request, it seems that the request is being setn twice to the server and in return we are getting a duplicated error xml response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response>
    <redirect url="/saraweb/inicio.jsf"></redirect>
    <changes>
        <extension aceCallbackParam="validationFailed">{"validationFailed":false}</extension>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response>
    <redirect url="/saraweb/inicio.jsf"></redirect>
</partial-response>
```

Extra oddities:

- The application works fine ONCE, after server restart.
- The application works fine ONCE, after clearing browser cache.
- The same war works fine in the same JBoss version in another machine.

Technologies used:

java 1.6, jsf 2.1, icefaces 3.3.

Redirect is done through navigation handler configured in faces-config.xml.

I just need help to figure out what's wrong. Thank you

Comment: Likely related to session expiration/renewal and something going wrong in IceFaces ajax response writer: http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/17542.page

Comment: No session expiration is involved here. @BalusC you're my only hope, i can't believe you haven't seen anything like this!!

Comment: I haven't really used IceFaces. If I were you, I would start looking around in its `PartialViewContext` implementation, if any.